# Dictionary() is not supported anymore in tm package. How to emend code?

Tags: r, tm

I just noticed that after updating to `tm` v. 0.5-10 the function `Dictionary()` is not supported anymore. Is this an mistake? Or was it deprecated? Am I suppose to use another function to create a dictionary?

Since I have many lines of code to emend now, what's the best way to proceed without engineering everything?

Comment: From the package news: "use a character vector instead; use Terms() to extract terms from a document-term or term-document matrix" http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/news.html

Comment: @Ben Terms() doesn't exactly replicate Dictionary() `Error in UseMethod("Terms") : 
  no applicable method for 'Terms' applied to an object of class "character"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As IShouldBuyABoat says, you haven't given us any clue about how you're using `Dictionary` so we can't really give you any specific answers (do update your question with more details).

In any case, the answer your question of 'how to update my code' is probably 'just delete `Dictionary` and it should be fine', as you can see here:

```
library(tm)
data(crude)
```

Find out what `Dictionary` did in earlier versions of the `tm` package:

```
methods(Dictionary)
getAnywhere(Dictionary.DocumentTermMatrix)
# function(x) structure(Terms(x), class = c("Dictionary", "character"))
getAnywhere(Dictionary.character)
# function (x)  structure(x, class = c("Dictionary", "character"))
```

Kind of a pointless function anyway, seems quite sensible to remove it. But how to update your code that depended on it?

You may have used `Dictionary` like this:

```
myDictionary <- Dictionary(c("some", "tokens", "that", "I", "am", "interested", "in"))
inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(crude, list(dictionary = myDictionary)))
```

Now that this function is not longer available, you'd do this instead, using a character vector: '

```
myTerms <- c("some", "tokens", "that", "I", "am", "interested", "in")
inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(crude, list(dictionary = myTerms)))
```

The output for these two examples is identical, first one was using `tm` version 0.5-9 and the second with version 0.5-10

The instruction in the NEWS to use `Terms` is if you want to get all the words in a document term matrix, like so

```
Terms(DocumentTermMatrix(crude))
```

If none of that helps you then you'll need to supply more detail about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Dictionary as @Ben suggested, I think you could create a dummy function called `Dictionary` which just returned the character vector you passed to it.

```
Dictionary <- function(x) {
    if( is.character(x) ) {
        return (x)
    }
    stop('x is not a character vector')
}
```

However, longer term, it's probably better to roll up your sleeves and refactor the code.

Answer (score 1):

A more complete extract from the NEWS file:

```
\subsection{DEPRECATED & DEFUNCT}{
    \itemize{
      \item Following functions have been removed:
      \itemize{
        \item \code{Dictionary()} (use a character vector instead; use
          \code{Terms()} to extract terms from a document-term or term-document 
          matrix),
```

So. yes, it is deprecated and removed. And as Ben suggested, the authors intend you to use `Terms()`. Why you get the error is a matter only for idle speculation since you have not provided a data object and code  the throws the error. One guess is that the object you are providing is not a TDM or DTM.