# Error in tm_map with dictionary

Tags: r, tm, word-cloud

I using below code to text mine -    http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld201213/ldhansrd/text/130110-0002.htm#13011048001187

I copied couple of paragraphs to a text file and ran below code.

```
   require(SnowballC)
   require(tm)
   require(wordcloud)

   getwd()
   src = paste0(getwd(),"/input")
   lords <- Corpus (DirSource(src))
   #inspect(lords)

   lords <- tm_map(lords, stripWhitespace)
   lords <- tm_map(lords, tolower)
   lords <- tm_map(lords, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

   lords <- tm_map(lords, removeWords, "noble")
   lords <- tm_map(lords, removeWords, c("lord","need","will"))

   dictCorpus = lords
   lords <- tm_map(lords, stemDocument, dictionary=dictCorpus)
   wordcloud(lords, scale=c(5,0.5)
      , max.words=100
      , random.order=FALSE
      , rot.per=0.35
      , use.r.layout=FALSE
      , colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

but I get below error 
    lords <- tm_map(lords, stemDocument, dictionary=dictCorpus)
    Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) :

```
  unused argument (dictionary = c("   anxiety among  involved  sickle cell services   complexity   services needed effectively places  largely outside  scope   clinical commissioning groups. many  concerned   type  policies     place  ensure   patient-centred, integrated approach  care engages primary care  community interests across health, social  community care.    help  reduce morbidity, needless hospital care   health inequalities experienced   seriously marginalised sector.", "", "  expectations    ccgs  local health  well- boards  aim  reflect  make-   respective client communities. , given   steady establishment  ccgs   view  community provision  sickle cell disorder management   major role  play across  country, especially  high-risk areas within ccgs, can  minister tell  house  priority   given  ccgs  people   sickle cell  thalassaemia community,   feeling concerned, vulnerable  anxious   situation   future?",
```

"", " yet,    cure  sickle cell   research  needed    cur"

when I execute 
    lords <- tm_map(lords, stemDocument, dictionary=dictCorpus)

Comment: With no data set you're unlikely to get a response.

Comment: Dictionary object needs to be a character vector, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21795019/1036500) for an example.

Comment: It has a a data set .. I have added full error to my original question.

Comment: try   `lords <- tm_map(lords, stemDocument, dictionary=Terms(dictCorpus))`  (untested, off-the-top of my head)