# is this equivalent to Dictionary() in R?

Tags: r, dictionary

I was following a book about machine learning in R and got the following code:

```
sms_train<-apply(sms_train,MARGIN=2,convert_counts)
sms_dtm_train <- sms_dtm[1:4169, ]
```

and in the book it says:

> To save this list of frequent terms for use later, we'll use the
>   Dictionary()  function:

```
sms_dict <- Dictionary(findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train, 5))
```

but the problem is that the new tm() library does not have the Dictionary() function included in its new version. I would like to know if this line is equivalent:

```
sms_dict<-findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train,5)
```

Thanks to a below comment here, I found that I can use the Terms() function to do something like:

```
sms_dict<-Terms(sms_dtm_train)
```

The main problem is that I cannot use the findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train,5), so my program will not work correctly.

any help?

Comment: Perhaps this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790353/dictionary-is-not-supported-anymore-in-tm-package-how-to-emend-code) gives some ideas

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790353/dictionary-is-not-supported-anymore-in-tm-package-how-to-emend-code