# issue with Dictionary() function in R

Tags: r, dictionary

I have been following an example of Bayesian classifiers according to the book of Lantz entitled "Machine Learning with R". The case is a spam classifier that works with the data of the following link:

http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~tiago/smsspamcollection/

In the code I have a problem in this part:

```
sms_train<-DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_train,list(dictionary=sms_dict))
sms_test<-DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_test,list(dictionary=sms_dict))
```

because it says that I should use the following instruction:

```
sms_dict <- Dictionary(findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train, 5))
```

The problem is that the Dictionary() function has been deprecated from new versions of tm. What I should do to accomplish what the books says:

> A dictionary is a data structure allowing us to specify which words
>   should appear in a document term matrix. To limit our training and
>   test matrixes to only the words in the preceding dictionary, use the
>   following command

I have done the following:

```
sms_dict<-findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train,5)
sms_train<-DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_train,list(dictionary=sms_dict))
sms_test<-DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_test,list(dictionary=sms_dict))
```

But I am sure that I am not limiting the test matrices at it says in the book. Even though the code is working, it does not give me the right results. What can I modify in this case?

The complete code for tracking purposes is the following:

```
sms_raw<-read.csv("sms_spam.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
install.packages("tm")
library(tm)
sms_corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(sms_raw$text))
corpus_clean<-tm_map(sms_corpus,content_transformer(tolower))
corpus_clean<-tm_map(corpus_clean,removeNumbers)
corpus_clean<-tm_map(corpus_clean,removeWords,stopwords())
corpus_clean<-tm_map(corpus_clean,stripWhitespace)
sms_dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus_clean)
sms_raw_train<-sms_raw[1:4169,]
sms_raw_test<-sms_raw[4170:5559,]
sms_dtm_train<-sms_dtm[1:4169,]
sms_dtm_test<-sms_dtm[4170:5559,]
sms_corpus_train<-corpus_clean[1:4169]
sms_corpus_test<-corpus_clean[4170:5559]
sms_dict<-findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train,5)
sms_train<-DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_train,list(dictionary=sms_dict))
sms_test<-DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_test,list(dictionary=sms_dict))
convert_counts<-function(x){
x<-ifelse(x>0,1,0)
x<-factor(x,levels=c(0,1),labels=c("No","Yes"))
return(x)
}
sms_train<-apply(sms_train,MARGIN=2,convert_counts)
sms_test<-apply(sms_test,MARGIN=2,convert_counts)
library(e1071)
sms_classifier<-naiveBayes(sms_train,sms_raw_train$type)
sms_test_pred<-predict(sms_classifier,sms_test)
install.packages("gmodels")
library(gmodels)
CrossTable(sms_test_pred,sms_raw_test$type,prop.chisq=FALSE,prop.t=FALSE,dnn=c('predicted','actual'))
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you have used `findFreqTerms` correctly as a dictionary. Your way fully replaces the former `Dictionary()` function, check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790353/dictionary-is-not-supported-anymore-in-tm-package-how-to-emend-code). Could you please explain more clearly how your expected output differs from the one you currently get? This will make it easier to track down the issue.

Comment: Aren't this `[1:4169,]` and `[4170:5559]` actually limiting your test matrices? Since you use a big portion for the training and later you have your smaller test set. But maybe I am completely off since I don't understand your code. It is hard to read with no proper spacing and unlogic variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by doing:

```
CrossTable(sms_test_pred[["class"]], sms_raw_test$Type, prop.chisq = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, dnn = c('predicted','actual'))
```