# Inspect a DocumentTermMatrix in R using BigramTokenizer and a dictionary with defined terms

Tags: r, dictionary, tm

I have a problem with the tm package that occurs after updating my R version to the newest one (R 3.4.2.).

I would like to inspect a DocumentTermMatrix using a dictionary with predefined list of terms (single and compound). Therefore I have applied the BigramTokenizer Function on my data corpus using the following code:

```
data <- c("This example shows how to apply dictionaries in text mining", 
      "supervised learning methods work with training data", 
      "unsupervised learning methods are great")
data.corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(data))
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 3))

inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(data.corpus, control =  list(tokenize=BigramTokenizer, dictionary = c("example", "dictionaries", "text mining", "supervised learning  methods"))))
```

After updating R I get the following error message:

```
Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i, j, v, nrow = length(terms), ncol = length(corpus),  : 'i, j' invalid
```

I have tried to find a solution for the problem on the web, but the hint with the snowball package does not work since this package doesn't exist anymore. Is there any possibility to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: works for me under R version 3.4.1, RWeka_0.4-35, and tm_0.7-1

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790353/dictionary-is-not-supported-anymore-in-tm-package-how-to-emend-code), maybe this is helpful concerning the depreciated `Dictionary()` function. And concerning the stemming package, have you looked for `SnowballC`?

Comment: Yes I checked it with the SnowballC package but it didn't fix the problem. I also tried to run the code as suggested in the link provided by you Manuel, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Maybe you could provide the output of `sessionInfo()` in a session in which you encountered the error so we can see if there are any issues regarding the versions you use.

Comment: Yes sure: R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 ...
Matrix products: default
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
 [1] openNLP_0.2-6      SnowballC_0.5.1    wordnet_0.1-13     tm_0.7-2          
 [5] NLP_0.1-11         RWeka_0.4-36       stringr_1.2.0      slam_0.1-40       
 [9] cluster_2.0.6      ggplot2_2.2.1      lda_1.4.2          topicmodels_0.2-7 
[13] wordcloud_2.5      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 proxy_0.4-19       stringi_1.1.6